# Share a folder on OS X that can be accessed by another user remotely

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I have a very quick and simple question that sadly has no answer so far.

I have two machines at home with OS X Snow Leopard, and I would like to share a folder on one of the drives on my main machine, with my laptop (a picture folder with gigabytes upon gigabytes of data, that I would like to access from the laptop).

So far my first thought was to do something like going into the info panel for that folder, and create a user with read only permission for that folder; then i would just go on the laptop, select the main computer and log in using that username... so the folder should show up with the drop box folder and the shared folder.

Sadly it won't work; when I log in i see only the dropbox; I've double checked the permission on the folder and it has the read only set for the user that I have created.

Is there anything else that I have to do to share this folder with the laptop? tried to search around but usually people share folders between users on the same computer, or share the whole drive with other users with other computers (in that case is much easier, but I need to share just a folder, not the whole drive).

Any help would be more than appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open System Preferences, go to the Sharing preference pane, and select File Sharing. Add the folder you want to share to that list.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, tried that too but it won't work.

So far I am not able to give access to just that folder to anyone; if i share the whole drive then i can share the folder, but this defy the purpose of having the drive not accessible while just that folder should be accessible.

Comment: @newbiez If you enable file sharing, administrators on your machine can access the whole drive. Is this the issue? You can create new "sharing only" users on your Mac and share the specific folder with them.